# keeping radio buttons checked after form submit

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have two set of radio buttons in html form `button` and `button1`. I am using below code to

1.keep the default value checked **(`question1` for first set and `answer2` for next set)**

2.keep  user radio button selection after the form submit

```
<div id="button_set1">
<input onClick="show_seq_lunid();" type="radio" name="button" value="Yes" <?php if(isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Yes')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> checked /><label>question1</label>   
<input onClick="show_list_lunid();" type="radio" name="button" value="No" <?php if(isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'No')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label>answer1</label>
</div>

<div id="button_set2">
<input onClick="os_hpux();" type="radio" name="button1" value="Yes" <?php if(isset($_POST['button1']) && $_POST['button1'] == 'Yes')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label>question2</label>   
<input onClick="os_others();" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" <?php if(isset($_POST['button1']) && $_POST['button1'] == 'No')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> checked /><label>answer2</label>
</div>
```

Here if i use below code, the second radio button `button1` is not  sticking on to the user selection after form submit, it changing back to its default checked state.ie `answer2`. But the first set of radio buttons work fine.
If I remove the default `checked` option from the code, both radio buttons working fine after form submit. How can I keep the radio button checked after form submit while using `checked` default option for radios

Comment: You need some server side magic for that. Are you using php on backend?

Comment: You have to pass your element status back with the form processing.

Comment: your logic is sound but not applied correctly... if nobody can answer in 10 min, I will... eating atm :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the problem is you're setting the `checked` value twice upon form submission, resulting in selecting either the default value (from initial form state) or the value that has been submitted.

For this to work correctly, you'd need always use PHP to append the `checked` value to your radio elements, like this:

```
<div id="button_set1">
<input onClick="show_seq_lunid();" type="radio" name="button" value="Yes" <?php if(!isset($_POST['button']) || (isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'Yes')) echo ' checked="checked"'?> /><label>question1</label>   
<input onClick="show_list_lunid();" type="radio" name="button" value="No" <?php if(isset($_POST['button']) && $_POST['button'] == 'No')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label>answer1</label>
</div>

<div id="button_set2">
<input onClick="os_hpux();" type="radio" name="button1" value="Yes" <?php if(isset($_POST['button1']) && $_POST['button1'] == 'Yes')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label>question2</label>   
<input onClick="os_others();" type="radio" name="button1" value="No" <?php if(!isset($_POST['button1']) || (isset($_POST['button1']) && $_POST['button1'] == 'No'))  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label>answer2</label>
</div>
```

Here's a working preview: http://codepad.viper-7.com/rbInpX

Also, please note that you're using *inline JavaScript notation* which is normally discouraged to keep dynamic JS content separate and more manageable ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem recently, but had a lot more radio buttons to deal with, so I thought I'd abstract away the value checking functionality into a method that also creates the radio button itself, therefore minimising repetitive value-checking code. I've reworked mine to suit your variable names:

```
function createRadioOption($name, $value, $onClickMethodName, $labelText) {

  $checked = '';
  if ((isset($_POST[$name]) && $_POST[$name] == $value)) {
    $checked = ' checked="checked"';
  }

  echo('<input onClick="'. $onClickMethodName .'();" type="radio" name="'. $name .'" value="'. $value .'"'. $checked .' /><label>'. $labelText .'</label>');
}

<div id="button_set1">
<?php createRadioOption('button', 'Yes', 'show_seq_lunid', 'question1'); ?>
<?php createRadioOption('button', 'No', 'show_list_lunid', 'question1'); ?>
</div>

<div id="button_set2">
<?php createRadioOption('button1', 'Yes', 'os_hpux', 'question2'); ?>
<?php createRadioOption('button1', 'No', 'os_others', 'question2'); ?>
</div>
```