# How to pass the value of a radio button in session using PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass the value of a radio button into a session in php but 
 i can't figure out how to do it! What i want is when the radio button is
 checked to give a value of 1.

I have done it with a text field with success like that :

```
name<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php  
 if(isset($_POST['name']))echo $_POST['name'];?>" required><br>
```

How can i do it in a similar way like that?

Comment: The code you have shown doesn’t have anything to do with sessions. Do you want to pre-check the radio button the user selected, when the form is shown again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097320/keeping-radio-buttons-checked-after-form-submit

Comment: If memory serves me correctly HTML form radio buttons pass a value of 1 (true) when the form is submitted. No PHP required for the value. On the server side you can process for the form_data, handling the radio button value at that time.

Comment: Instead of an echo use a session to store it inside.